# Get update time ACF field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a table, in this table show post items, in the post have a acf field with data, so, I want to show the editing date/time of acf field in the table.

example:

---

### | post-name | acf field item | editing time |

How I can get update time/date acf fields?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you have written any code?

Answer (score 0):

ACF does not keep track of when it is edited. WordPress posts themself do have a `post_modified` field.

If you want to specifically know when a ACF field is updated. You will have to build that yourself.
ACF has hooks to do this kind of thing. The [acf/update_value](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-update_value/) hook is probably the one you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try